# Django queryset annotate

Tags: django-models

Hi guys I'm a newbie trying to create an App in Django now I need to run a query with F expressions everything ok, but when I try to make a Sum to get two totals fields the rest of the annotate fields just disappear

```
query = FinalReport.objects.values('customers', 'currency_desc','design_fee' ,
    'currency', 'month', 'year', 'categories')\
    .annotate(pairs=F('total_lenses')/2, invoice=ExpressionWrapper(F('pairs') * F('design_fee'),
    output_field=DecimalField(decimal_places=1000, max_digits=5)), total_pairs=Sum(F('total_lenses')/2))
```

when I run this the pairs field and invoice fields values just gone. and the  total_pairs field doesn't show either Django don't show any error.

Answer (score 0):

Have You tried this:

```
query = FinalReport.objects.values('customers', 'currency_desc', 'design_fee',
                                   'currency', 'month', 'year', 'categories') \
    .annotate(pairs=F('total_lenses') / 2,)\
    .annotate(invoice=ExpressionWrapper(F('pairs') * F('design_fee'),
                                        output_field=DecimalField(decimal_places=1000, max_digits=5)))\
    .annotate(total_pairs=Sum(F('total_lenses') / 2))
```

I've noticed that annotate gets confused sometimes, separating it could help.

Comment: Are you actually able to define `decimal_places` in the `ExpressionWrapper `?  I've had no luck in getting this to work `.annotate(discount_amount=ExpressionWrapper(F('list_price') *F('discount_rate'), output_field=DecimalField(decimal_places=2)))`